# How do you customize the border of a UISegmentedControl in swift

Tags: swift, border, swift2, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm trying to make make the top border of a UI segmented control one color and the bottom border of a UISegmented control another color.  I can do it with a UIView, but it doesn't work correctly with a segmented control for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use custom divider images.

Please refer either to "[Customizing appearance of UISegmentedControl](http://techblog.chegg.com/2013/01/11/customizing-appearance-of-uisegmentedcontrol/)" article or "[UIKit User Interface Catalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UISegmentedControl.html)" topic.