# Summing the constants for the vertical constraints for the subviews in a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying to set the height of a UIView by taking the sum of all its subviews vertical constraints.  How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Use `UIStackView`, the height is automatically calculated.

Comment: When and where do you want to do this?

Comment: It's mostly to help answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33403841/how-do-you-customize-the-border-of-a-uisegmentedcontrol-in-swift/33404400#33404400